# Powershell/bat - copy folder to multiple destinations

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have folder c:\tocopy that I would like to copy the content to c:\dest1, c:\dest2 and overriding the existing files
I am not sure what my script would need to look like to be able to do this.
(using win2k12)
Thank you

Comment: Question flagged as there is an obvious lack of effort put into the question.  Quickly searching would result in numerous examples and sample scripts that could have been adapted to fit the authors question.  Then the question be posted to show the script and an error or explain the observed behavior versus expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

would use robocopy for this purpose.

http://www.windows-commandline.com/robocopy-switches-syntax-examples/
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx
http://improve.dk/simple-file-synchronization-using-robocopy/

In this particular case:

```
robocopy c:\tocopy c:\dest1 /MIR /Z
robocopy c:\tocopy c:\dest2 /MIR /Z
```

**/MIR** makes dest mirror tocopy

**/Z** makes it so that the copy is restartable (depending on the size of the things you are copying you may not need this, but you probably want it when transferring files over the network or doing large copies

Comment: Provided link has some examples. I edited the answer to put some in here directly

Answer (score 0):

To use powershell, try the [copy-item cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849793.aspx):

```
Copy-Item c:\tocopy -Destination c:\dest1 -Recurse -Force
Copy-Item c:\tocopy -Destination c:\dest2 -Recurse -Force
```